# Selecting text on modal dialog also selecting text in background

Tags: modal-dialog, microsoft-edge, textselection

After the latest windows 10 update to 1809, text selection on modal window is selecting text on the parent window (background).
Edge version - 44.17763.1.0
EdgeHTML 18.17763

This is working in chrome and older versions of Edge browser.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tested [this demo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/) in my Edge 44.18362.1.0, EdgeHTML 18.18362. It will not select the parent window when I select text on modal window. The result is like below:

[image]

The latest version of windows 10 is 1903. You could update to the latest version of windows 10 and the Edge will also be updated and then try it again.

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try.

Comment: You're welcome. You could let us know about the status update about the issue, if there's any further issue or if the issue has been solved.

Comment: This is still an issue in Microsoft Edge. Opened a ticket with Microsoft, they are investigating the root cause.
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G8C1MH37OPNY

Comment: I reproduce the issue with the example you provided. I find that the issue occurs when the modal dialog is in an iframe. Thank you for submitting the feedback to Microsoft regarding this issue.

Comment: @KrishnaSantoshNidri do you have any update on this issue? Can you share the link to the bug report?

Comment: Microsoft said they identified the issue and have a fix. However, they are not going to ship since the old edge is deprecated. They suggested us to move to new chromium based edge.